# Как передать изображение в плеер через data- атрибут?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediaplayer

Кнопкой плей передаются значения в аудио-плеер

```
<a data-image="image.jpg">play</a>
```

А плеер допустим такой

```
<div class="jp-image">вот здесь нужно вывести картинку image.jpg</div>
```

Что нужно прописать в JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По клику на ссылку берем ее data атрибут и кладем его в src атрибут картинки, которую в свою очередь кладем в див jp-image

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('a').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault;
            $('.jp-image').html('<img src="'+$(this).data('image')+'">');
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Отлично! Всё работает. Спасибо!